# code from hackers delight

Tags: c++

```
/* Converts the unsigned integer k to binary character form with a blank
after every fourth digit.  Result is in string s of length 39.  Caution:
If you want to save the string, you must move it.  This is intended for
use with printf, and you can have only one reference to this in each
printf statement. */
char * binary(unsigned k) {
   int i, j;
   static char s[40] = "0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000";

   j = 38;
   for (i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (k & 1) s[j] = '1';
      else       s[j] = '0';
      j = j - 1;
      k = k >> 1;
      if ((i & 3) == 0) j = j - 1;
   }
   return s;
}
```

i have tested  it in c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char *binary(unsigned k){

    int i, j;
    static char s[40]="0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000";
    j=38;
    for (i=31;i>=0;i--){
        if (k & 1) s[j]='1';
        else s[j]='0';
        j=j-1;
        k=k>>1;
        if ((i & 3)==0) j=j-1;
    }
    return s;
}

int main(){

    unsigned k;
    cin>>k;
    *binary(k);

    return 0;
}
```

but what value  does k have ? for example i have entered 127 but it return 0 why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're throwing away the return value of the function `binary` :

```
*binary(k);
```

`binary` returns a `char *` which is (as the documentation says) "intended for use with printf", but you aren't doing anything with this string. Your program 'returns' 0 because that's what you're explicitly returning with your last line of code!

Try changing

```
*binary(k);
```

to

```
cout << binary(k);
```

and you should at least see *some* output.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
  cin>>k;
  *binary(k);
```

to:

```
   cin >> k;
   cout << binary(k) << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should print out the binary string?

```
unsigned k;
cin >> k;
cout << binary(k) << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this C++ code instead:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char *binary(unsigned k){
  int i, j;
  static char s[40]="0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000";
  j=38;
  for (i=31;i>=0;i--) {
    if (k & 1) s[j]='1';
    else s[j]='0';
    j=j-1;
    k=k>>1;
    if ((i & 3)==0) 
      j=j-1;
  }
  return s;
}

int main(){
  unsigned k;
  cin>>k;
  cout << k << " : " <<  binary(k) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Notice that this line has changed:

```
cout << *binary(k);
```

Answer (score 0):

As it should. I'm not all that familiar with C++, but the basics are still the same. The `*binary` function returns the value back to the previous function, it doesn't return that value for the entire page.

For example:

```
k = myFunction();
return 0;
```

Your `myFunction` gets executed and that returned value gets set into the variable `k`, then it continues the rest of the function and returns `0`.